# How to generate hierachy from treeview

Tags: c#, treeview

I have populated a treeview using this code:

```
        private void updateTree()
    {
        treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
        List<TreeNode> graphicsNodes = new List<TreeNode>();
        foreach (Graphic graphic in graphics)
        {
            List<TreeNode> templateNodes = new List<TreeNode>();
            foreach (Template template in graphic.templates)
            {
                List<TreeNode> aliasNodes = new List<TreeNode>();
                foreach(Alias alias in template.aliases)
                {
                    aliasNodes.Add(new TreeNode(alias.aliasName + ": " + alias.aliasValue));
                }
                templateNodes.Add(new TreeNode(template.templateName, aliasNodes.ToArray()));
            }
            graphicsNodes.Add(new TreeNode(graphic.fileName.Replace(".g", ""), templateNodes.ToArray()));
        }
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("Graphics", graphicsNodes.ToArray()));
    }
```

After manipulating, renaming and deleting some of these elements in the TreeView, is it possible to rebuild my Grapics structure with the new values?

This structure is built so that each Graphic has many Templates and each Template has many Aliases, this code is defined as follows:

```
public class Graphic
{
    public string filePath;
    public string fileName;
    public List<Template> templates;

    public Graphic(List<Template> _templates, string fpath, string fName)
    {
        templates = _templates;
        fileName = fName;
        filePath = fpath;
    }
}
public class Template
{
    public List<Alias> aliases;
    public string templateName;
    public Template(string instString, string userdataString)
    {
        templateName = (instString.Replace("inst ", "").Replace(" 0 0", "")).Replace(" ","");
        aliases = new List<Alias>();
        string[] aliasStrings = userdataString.Replace("\"","").Split(new string[1] { "text_alias" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (string segment in aliasStrings)
        {
            if (segment.Contains("userdata")) { continue; }
            string aliasString = "text_alias" + segment;
            string[] sections = aliasString.Split('^');
            aliases.Add(new Alias(sections[0].Replace("text_alias=", ""), (sections[1].Replace("text_exp_flag=", "") == "1"), sections[2].Replace("alias_new_name=", ""), sections[3].Replace("alias_value=", ""))); //Sorry!
        }
    }
}
public class Alias
{
    public string aliasName;
    public string aliasValue;
    public string newName;
    public bool expectedFlag;

    public Alias(string name, bool expected, string nName, string value)
    {
        aliasName = name;
        aliasValue = value;
        newName = nName;
        expectedFlag = expected;
    }
}
```

If this is not easily achievable, what would be the best way to approach this from a different angle?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
for (int i = 0; i <= dst.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                nodeTables.Nodes.Add(dst.Tables[0].Rows[i]["SchemaName"].ToString() + "." + dst.Tables[0].Rows[i]["TableName"].ToString());
                nodeTables.Nodes[i].ImageIndex = 2;
                nodeTables.Nodes[i].Nodes.Add("Columns");

                //Filling the Column Names
                DataSet dstCol = new DataSet();
                dstCol = common.GetColumns(Convert.ToInt32(dst.Tables[0].Rows[i]["object_Id"]));

                for (int col = 0; col <= dstCol.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; col++)
                {
                    nodeTables.Nodes[i].Nodes[0].ImageIndex = 0;
                    nodeTables.Nodes[i].Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(dstCol.Tables[0].Rows[col]["name"].ToString());
                    nodeTables.Nodes[i].Nodes[0].Nodes[col].ImageIndex = 1;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Any chance I could have a quick explanation as to what that's actually doing please?

Comment: the code is drawing a hierarchy from SQL database , the DataSet object dst contains the Schema in a tabular structure, in every for loop iteration, it draws the schemaname and then fetches the columnName and then creates a childNode to arrange the ColumnNames. Here the col is the columnindex

Comment: My hierarchy isn't in a sql db